# How to tts correctly quotes in Festival?

Tags: festival

I'm using `Festival` for `tts`. But it doesn't read correctly quotes (apostrophes) (e.g. the words like `can't`, `it's` etc.

Can I do something to fix it?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oz3DutXbCoM-_sne-OXsf1_TQlL-SEG3/view?usp=share_link) is the output of [this](https://openai.com/blog/governance-of-superintelligence) text.

Comment: In what way is it not correct? How exactly do you use `Festival`? What input do you use? Single words or a sentence? What output do you get? What do you expect instead?

Comment: @Bodo I edited the question.

Comment: The words in the text are actually `can’t` and `it’s` with what appears to be unicode [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm). Did you take any steps to preprocess the text, for example `iconv -t ascii/translit yourtext | festival --tts`?

Comment: I guess you get the unexpected result because the apostrophes are not apostrophes (U+0027, `'`, 0x27) but right single quotes (Unicode U+2019, `’`, 0xe2 0x80 0x99) which look similar, but are wrong.

Comment: You're right, it's similar character, I haven't noticed it or rather didn't know there is a difference. When I change it to `'` it reads correctly. Thank you.